# Write an equation showing a condition indicating correlation between two variables

Tags: equations, statistics, mathematics

I am trying to write this conditional equation:

[image]

I am not sure what could be the mathematical syntax for saying:

**"variables `x` and `y` are correlated".**

While searching for this, I came to know that it is really tough to find such a thing. Please let me know if you aware of such a mathematical syntax.

In addition, I am also curious to know how would following be written in an equation.

1. "variables `x` and `y` are **anti**-correlated"
2. "variables `x` and `y` are **significantly** correlated"
3. "variables `x` and `y` are correlated, **while accounting for a covariate `z`**"
4. "variables `x` and `y` are correlated **based on ranks**" (as in Spearman's correlations)

Comment: Wrong site? This looks more appropriate for mathSE.